# IPA with enterprise account showing warning message on install

Tags: ios, ipa, enterprise-distribution

When deploying an in house app using the Enterprise account users get this alert when installing the .ipa

Alert image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5tsF.png

The alert says that the app developer is not authorized...
Is there any way to avoid it ?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when the provisioning profile you have used to create .ipa file not contain the device UDID in which you are trying to install & failed.

Comment: The ipa is build using an enterprise account which doesn't need you to specify the UDIDs... or at least I think so... :)